# Robocopy issues with cloud files

Tags: robocopy, windows-backup

I’d like `Robocopy` to copy all useful data from a Windows system drive, but, for some reason, `robocopy` doesn't know how to tell apart certain OneDrive files *(I guess Google drive and iCloud may have the same issue)*; even when adding `/XA:O`, `robocopy` still tries to copy them over, producing failures *(same if `/XJ` is used to exclude symbolic links)*.

What's wrong with these files and is there any way to make `Robocopy` ignore these files?

- The properties of these files show an actual size in Explorer, but with *Size on disk: 0bytes*
- I guess the only (inefficient) way to exclude these files is by excluding the full folders [`/XD:%UserProfile%\OneDrive`], which is somewhat cumbersome because a system drive may include an assortment of offline applications and data (such as iCloud, onedrive and google drive folders in each user profile): 
   [image: onedrive file]

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. Those files are using the 'Files on demand' feature of OneDrive. The files you see are a 'stub' referencing the file in the cloud, hence it has the correct size of the file shown under properties, but is taking up zero space on the disk.
If you run the Windows ATTRIB /? command, you will see some new attribute options. Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/files-on-demand-windows.
Robocopy has not been updated to know about these attributes, therefore you cannot exclude them.

"Always available" - Pinned - attrib +p 
"Locally available" - Clearpin - attrib -p 
"Online-only" - Unpinned - attrib +u

If you were doing this often by running a script, you could add a silent uninstall of any file sync apps to the start of the script, seeing as they are backed up in the cloud anyway.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is what happens when robots are in control.  Question is "What's wrong with these files and is there any way to make Robocopy ignore these files?"  Answer is "They are Files on Demand and No".  Not good enough for the bot! LOL 

Answer (score 0):

[`RoboCopy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) is extremely inefficient at backing up files/partitions and would not be recommended in any use case since it lacks compression and has no parity to ensure files aren't corrupted in the backup; instead, capturing a [WIM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wim-vs-ffu-image-file-formats) with [`Dism`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14) would be recommended:

- WIMs/ESDs are smart compression image formats and therefore storage efficient:

  - Only changed files are added to an `.esd`/`.wim` when a new image [index] is appended to it; newly appended images utilize the same copy of unchanged files already contained within the image *([hash verified](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wim-vs-ffu-image-file-formats))*, allowing for an image to remain small in relation to the data within
  - Data within an ESD/WIM is impossible to corrupt if imaging commands are *always* issued with `/Verify` and `/CheckIntegrity` *(Windows ≤7: `/Check`)*
- Windows XP ≥ 10 has always natively supported imaging of partitions/filesystems:

  - A System [OS] partition can only be imaged from WinPE/WinRE

    - [WIM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13096)s [**W**indows **IM**age] can capture an entire partition or individual folders/files
    - ESDs [**E**lectronic **S**oftware **D**istribution] can only capture a System partition and must use  `/Compress:Recovery` *(algorithm is ~33% more efficient than `/Compress:Max`)*

      - Windows ≥10: Can only be used for exported [PBR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/push-button-reset-overview) [**P**ush-**B**utton **R**eset] images 
         Windows ≤8.1: Only a bootable Windows install can be captured as an ESD
  - `Dism` is always included within WinPE/WinRE *(Win XP ≤ 7: `ImageX`)*:

    - **WinPE:** **Win**dows **P**reinstallation **E**nvironment 
       *(Windows Setup boot media: **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>** to access terminal)*
    - **WinRE:** **Win**dows **R**ecovery **E**nvironment 
       *(WinRE is a WinPE image containing extra [WinPE Optional Components](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference) vital to recovery)*

---

#### Imaging

<sup>*([cmdlet mapping](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/use-dism-in-windows-powershell-s14))*</sup> 
Specify exclusions or exceptions by creating a [`WimScript.ini`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-configuration-list-and-wimscriptini-files-winnext) config file, with `/ScratchDir` being required in WinPE since it only has 32MB of scratch [temp] space by default:

1. **Either *Capture* or *Append* an image:**

   - **[Capture Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#capture-image):**

     ```powershell
     # Windows ≥8: DISM
       Dism /Capture-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2022.01.30 @ 09:00" /Compress:Max /CheckIntegrity /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:"

     # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
       ImageX /Capture "C:" "Z:\Base.esd" "Windows Backup" "Base Image 2022.01.30 @ 09:00" /Compress:Recovery /Check /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
     ```

     - Change `/Compress:Max` to `/Compress:Fast` if not saving captured image to an SSD
     - For size constraints, [**`/Split-Image`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#split-image) splits images into multiple read-only `.swm` files
   - **[Append Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#append-image):**

     ```powershell
     # Windows ≥8: DISM
       Dism /Append-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2022.01.30 @ 09:00" /CheckIntegrity /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:"

     # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
       ImageX /Append "C:" "Z:\Base.esd" "Windows Backup" "Base Image 2022.01.30 @ 09:00" /Compress:Recovery /Check /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
     ```

     - Compression is locked to the value set when the base image was captured
     - Indexes can be deleted [[**`/Delete-Image`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#delete-image)] or exported [[**`/Export-Image`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#export-image)] to their own image
2. **[Apply Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#apply-image):**

   ```powershell
   # Windows ≥8: DISM
     Dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /Index:1 /ApplyDir:"C:" /CheckIntegrity /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:"

   # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
     ImageX /Apply "Z:\Base.wim" 1 "C:" /Check /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
   ```

   - Prior to applying, [`/Get-ImageInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#get-imageinfo) to ensure correct index [image] is being applied:

     ```powershell
     Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim"
     ```
   - If applying an OS image, the following must be run prior to exiting WinPE/WinRE:

     - BIOS:

       ```powershell
       BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD
       ```
     - UEFI:

       ```powershell
       ::# With existing bootable EFI partition:
           BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD


       ::# Without existing bootable EFI partition:
           ::# Mount EFI partition on Y:
               DiskPart → lis vol → sel vol # → assign letter=Y → exit

           ::# Create EFI directories and enter:
               MkDir "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"
               Cd /d "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"

           ::# Create EFI boot structure:
               BootRec /Fixboot

               ::# If Access Denied error occurs (C: is applied image):
                   BcdBoot C:\Windows /s C: /f UEFI

           ::# Resolve any other boot issues:
               BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD

           ::# Unmount EFI partition:
               DiskPart → sel vol Y → remove → exit
       ```

---

#### Accessing data within an ESD/WIM:

1. **Read-only:**

   1. **[Mount Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#mount-image):** *(as `/ReadOnly`)*

      ```powershell
      # Windows ≥8: DISM
        Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /Index:2 /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /Optimize /CheckIntegrity /ReadOnly

      # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
        ImageX /Mount "Z:\Base.wim" 2 "C:\Mount" /Check
      ```

      - *In lieu of this, I prefer opening the `.wim`/`.esd` within the [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) GUI*
   2. **[Unmount Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#unmount-image):** *(`/discard` changes)*

      ```powershell
      # Windows ≥8: DISM
        Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /CheckIntegrity /Discard

      # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
        ImageX /Unmount "C:\Mount"
      ```
2. **Make changes, or add data, to an image [index]:**

   1. **Mount Image:**

      ```powershell
      # Windows ≥8: DISM
        Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /Index:2 /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /Optimize /CheckIntegrity

      # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
        ImageX /MountRW "Z:\Base.wim" 2 "C:\Mount" /Check
      ```
   2. **Unmount Image:** *(`/Commit` changes)*

      ```powershell
      # Windows ≥8: DISM
        Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /CheckIntegrity /Commit

      # Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX
        ImageX /Unmount "C:\Mount" /Commit
      ```

      - Save changes as a new appended image by adding `/Append`